# PL/SQL count(*) behaves differently in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have an empty table.

If I execute

```
select count(*) from table;
```

it returns 0;

However in PL/SQL, Sql*Plus

```
declare
   c number;
begin
   select count(*) into c from table;
   dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
```

Returns 572.

What's going on?

**------------------------------------------SOLVED----------------------------------**

So I had to do

```
delete from table;
```

in Sql*Plus, not in Toad.

However, I ran commit in both of them..

Comment: Are you running the queries as the same user (ie in the same tablespace)?

Comment: count(*) is SQL, even when the SQL is wrapped in PL/SQL

Comment: Yes I run the queries as the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit or rollback transactions. It seems that you have been working with the table. Without commit/rollback In different sessions you will have different results.

Comment: @otisonoza You must be connected to different schema then. Please run both code is a new session in SQL*Plus

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the SQL table has rows in it? The syntax looks correct for the SQL select. I imagine "table" will be your table name like: tblProducts? "Table" is a reserved keywork in MS SQL

Comment: There are 0 rows in the table, so the first example is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use i.e.:

```
DECLARE
   c NUMBER(10) := 0;
```

and then:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO c FROM table;
```

Comment: -1 ... count(1) gives exactly the same result as count(*), but it is a myth that there is a performance (or any functional) benefit.

Comment: It still returns 572.